# Compromised Ubuntu VM - How should I go about tearing it apart to figure out what happened?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, malware, esxi

Alright, here's the situation: the lab I work in has a dedicated virtual machine server running VMWare ESXi, with a number of virtual machines running on it. Our IT department started getting Fail2Ban emails Friday morning stating one of those VMs was hitting them with numerous malicious login attempts. The machine in question, an up-to-date Ubuntu LTS build, only has 2 users at the moment, and we're using it to run a dockerized postgres server, a Node.js server, and a JupyterLab server. Updates have been applied regularly (about once a week), and we make a habit of changing default passwords and the like. First thing I did was shutdown the server and take a snapshot.

One of these VMs has been compromised once before, so I'd like to dig in and figure out exactly what happened to try and prevent this in the future. I will, of course, burn this image to the ground and replace it with a fresh one, but I want to make sure we don't just stand up an equally vulnerable system.

What are recommended next steps to safely explore and figure out exactly how the machine was compromised?

Comment: can you give more details on the nature of the attack ? your VM was trying to login were using what? or were they receiving fail2ban email from your VM with login attempts?

Comment: Our abuse email got several emails from other servers' Fail2Ban installs, complaining about malicious login attempts from our VM. Here's a log line example:

Comment: `Note: Local timezone is +0100 (CET)
Feb 21 09:53:04 REDACTED sshd[11870]: Invalid user cpanelphppgadmin from <VM's IP> Feb 21 09:53:04 REDACTED sshd[11870]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<VM's IP> Feb 21 09:53:07 REDACTED sshd[11870]: Failed password for invalid user cpanelphppgadmin from <VM's IP> port 41490 ssh2 Feb 21 09:53:07 REDACTED sshd[11870]: Received disconnect from <VM's IP> port 41490:11: Bye Bye [preauth] Feb 21 09:53:07 REDACTED sshd[11870]: Disconnected from <VM's IP> port 41490 [preauth]`

Comment: I presume CPanel is not installed on any server within your network?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*While this may not be best practices, here's the approach I took, and what I learned. I'm documenting this mostly for future individuals with similar problems.*

Before anything else, I disabled the VM's network adapter in ESXi, so once I turned it on it wouldn't be able to continue attacks while I figured out what was going on. Then I booted it and accessed the machine through the ESXi desktop console.

I checked to see if there were any suspicious user logins with `last`, but didn't see anything out of the ordinary. Also opened the log to see if anything jumped out, but didn't find anything obviously wrong.

Next, I needed to check for rootkits and malware. Here's the iffy part: given that all the malicious activity I knew of was `ssh` based, I uninstalled the open-sshclient and server. While this wouldn't stop malware with its own ssh client baked in, I figured it was a good chance it would try to use the system's client.

I then re-enabled the network adapter, installed [chkrootkit](https://www.chkrootkit.org/) and [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/), and then quickly shut off the network adapter. I ran chkrootkit, which didn't find anything except marking basically all of our node_modules folders as suspicious. But ClamAV found 2 coin mining bots hidden in a `.bashtemp` folder in a non-admin test user's home folder. The malicious tools were cleverly masquerading as `cron` and `acron`.

My best guess is, since we neglected to install Fail2Ban on this machine, that the test user account lacked a properly strong password, and was compromised by some kind of self-proliferating coin mining bot net.